# FullSeriesCollection generates "Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found" in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I created a macro that adds data labels to the two series in my pivot chart.

```
Sub Data_Labels_On_Pivot2()
'
' Data_Labels_On_Pivot2 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 14").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End Sub
```

This works on machines running Excel 2013.

With Excel 2010 `.FullSeriesCollection(1)` generates an error:

> "Compile Error: Method or data member not found"

I googled this topic and was not able to find anything.  I did come across the ActiveX issues from the Windows update earlier this year and was not able to find any .exd files on the machine running Excel 2010 that I am testing with.

Comment: `FullSeriesCollection` was added in Excel 2013. See [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230578.aspx). What happens when you replace `FullSeriesCollection` object with `SeriesCollection`?

Comment: It works! I also had to remove this row: `Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False`. I'm not sure why. If you don't mind me asking, what is the difference between `FullSeriesCollection` and `SeriesCollection`?  My macro performs the same action with either in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 6):

`FullSeriesCollection` was [added in Excel 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj230578.aspx). It isn't a valid property in earlier versions.

Replace `FullSeriesCollection` with `SeriesCollection`, which is valid in Excel 2010.

Credits to [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout) who posted this answer as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482558/macro-works-in-2013-not-in-2010-with-compile-error-method-or-data-member-not/40917352?noredirect=1#comment52826221_32482558).

Comment: Can you (or @SiddharthRout) say if once changed from `FullSeriesCollection` to `SeriesCollection` in order to be compatible with excel 2010, will the same code still work in excel 2013?

Comment: @eli-k I guess it's just a question of trying and see if it works?

Comment: Well I did and it does - but this is just in one specific case. What I was wondering is whether there are scenarios where using `SeriesCollection` instead of `FullSeriesCollection` in excel 2013(+) might fail, and therefore require different versions of the code for different versions of Excel.